# Boxing a component of multi-aligned equation

Tags: equations, boxes

Suppose I have a multiply-aligned equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A &= B &&= C \\
  D &= E &&= F \\
  G &= H &&= I
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to box the last alignment section of my equation vertically, so something like (excuse my handiwork)

[image]

I've dug around in the [`mdframed`](http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) and [`tcolorbox`](http://chocolatshalba.ch/files/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) documentation, but as a relative noob I can't figure out how to span segments of a multi-line equation with a box like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done without a graphic package. I give a code below, and, for fun,  `pstricks` code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{aligned}
  A &= B = \\
  D &= E = \\
  G &= H =
\end{aligned}
\fboxsep =1pt
\boxed{\begin{aligned}
  & C \\
  & F\mkern1mu \\
 & I
\end{aligned}} \]

\begin{postscript}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A &= B &&= \pnode[0pt, 2.5ex]{C}C \\
  D &= E &&= F \\
  G &= H &&=I\pnode[6pt, -1ex]{I}
\end{alignat*}
\psset{linejoin=1, linecolor=IndianRed}
\psframe[linewidth=0.6pt](C)(I)
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one I can make the most sense of and seems very re-usable, thank you!

Comment: @Bernard +1 and for the change of the check for you and for the previous answers. After I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to go,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[black,#1]
      ($(#2)+(-0.2em,2.0ex)$) rectangle
      ($(#3)+(0.75em,-0.75ex)$);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A &= B &&= \tikzmark{top left} C \\
  D &= E &&= F \\
  G &= H &&= I \tikzmark{bottom right}
\end{alignat*}

\DrawBox[thin]{top left}{bottom right}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the size of the box, as well as other parameters in the preambule. This technique uses TikZ marks and overlay the frame on top of the alignat environment.

[image]

Romain

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A &= B &&= \tikznode{C}{C} \\
  D &= E &&= \tikznode{F}{F} \\
  G &= H &&= \tikznode{I}{I}
\end{alignat*}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[draw,blue,rounded corners,fit=(C) (F) (I)]{};}
% F is not required in this example but it will be if it is replaced by a object
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added something, please feel free to remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: @marmot, it seems fine by me, fit is probably more adequate :)

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer the color black and another background you can choose here:

```
set fill color=white,
set border color=blue,
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\tikzset{offset def/.style={
        above left offset={-.1,0.5},
        below right offset={.5,-1.3},
    },
    color def/.style={
        offset def,
        set fill color=white,
        set border color=blue,
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A &= B &&=\tikzmarkin[color def]{a} C \\
  D &= E &&= F \\
  G &= H &&= I
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```