# Boxing only some of the equations in an align environment

Tags: equations, boxes

I am looking to box some of the equations in an aligned environment, but not all. For example, I want to box the equations that are within the "max" and "s.t." sections, but not the "where" section of the below example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \max_{w,b,\xi} \quad & a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \nonumber\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}\\
        & 0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq n \\
        & a + 2b - c \geq 0 \\
    \textrm{where} \quad & n = 25\\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Desired result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

with the link [Boxing a component of multi-aligned equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432596/boxing-a-component-of-multi-aligned-equation)
I discover the hf-tikz package and with Sebastiano's code

MODIFIED after the comment

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
    % code de Sebastiano
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432596/boxing-a-component-of-multi-aligned-equation
    \tikzset{offset def/.style={
          above left offset={-1,0.5},%<-- réglages the boxe
          below right offset={2,-0.25},%<-- réglages the boxe
    },
    color def/.style={
          offset def,
          set fill color=white,
          set border color=black,%<-- réglage border color
    },
    }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
          \tikzmarkin[color def]{mark 1}\max_{w,b,\xi} \quad & a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \nonumber\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}\\
          & 0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq n \\
          & a + 2b - c \geq 0 \tikzmarkend{mark 1}\\
    \textrm{where} \quad & n = 25\\
    \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    In the hf-tikz package documentation p. 3
    \[\tikzmarkin{a-1}x+\dfrac{z}{y}=400\tikzmarkend{a-1}\]

    \begin{equation}
      \tikzmarkin[below right offset={0.1,-0.4},above left offset={-0.1,0.5}]
      {right delim frac 2}
      x+\dfrac{z}{y}=400
      \tikzmarkend{right delim frac 2}
      \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Modified 2
with alignedat

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

    \usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
    \begin{document}

    \tikzset{
        %offset def/.style={
        % above left offset={0,0},%<-- réglages the boxe
        % below right offset={0,0},%<-- réglages the boxe
        % },
        color def/.style={
                %offset def,
                set fill color=white,
                set border color=black,%<-- réglage border color
            },
    }
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
            \tikzmarkin[color def]{mark 99}\max_{w,b,\xi} \quad& a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \\
            \textrm{s.t.} \quad &a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}\\
            & 0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq n\\
            &a + 2b - c \geq 0&\tikzmarkend{mark 99}\\%<-- a colon additional
            \textrm{where} \quad & n = 25
        \end{alignedat}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: How would I adjust it to look like what would normally be produced by the `boxed` environment, i.e. sharp corners with black edges?

Comment: Also, how can I avoid using magic numbers for this? For example, if the equation on the `max` line was a fraction, it would peak above the box, or if any of the equations were longer they would extend past the box.

Comment: @jared, for the réglages of boxe with above left offset and below right offset, and the color with set border color=black. I modified the code. The documentation : https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz

Comment: @jared, with alignedat ans e new colon before the end mark, no more settings needed, BUT does not work with subequations